# Google Sheets hover label from different values

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I am working on a Google Spreadsheet with several columns of data. I have made a chart that pits two of those columns against each other, showing that in general, when one value increases, the other one decreases. When I hover over a datapoint, it mentions the exact value of both the x- and y-axis. However, I would like it to show the value from the same row in a different column, the label of the values I'm displaying, so I can easily see where the values belong. Is it possible to customise the hover label in this way? I could not find it in the graph settings and online search did not yield any results either.

This is an impression of the sheet I have:

```
Label  x-value  y-value
aaa    130      0
bbb    110      7
ccc    100      10
ddd    50       30
eee    75       23
fff    20       42
```

I would like the hover to show me `aaa` for the first value for example.

[image: Graph]

This is the real graph with a hover label:
`550`
`x: 49`
I would like it to show the "name" of that row instead.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet including your current chart, in order to clarify the situation?

Comment: @Iamblichus I added a screenshot of the graph with an example of the current hover label.

Comment: I'd suggest you to request this feature via `Help > Help sheets improve` on the Sheets editor.

Comment: I did, so I presume that this is currently not possible at all?